# How to find ghostscript files in ubuntu?

Tags: find, ghostscript

I'm working with the terminal and im trying to find ghostscript files in all the computer. How can I do that? I know that I must use the comand "find", but is there anything else I should type?

Answer (score 3):

If you want results that include recently created files, try this:

```
find / -type f -name \*.gs
```

However, if you want an answer quickly, instead of `find` try `locate`, which uses a database of files that is updated every night or every week

```
locate *.gs
```

Comment: .gs is Google Apps Script or GemStone Document or Geosoft Script. I think it is .ps (postscript) that is used for ghostscript files (??)

Comment: GS can read .ps files, along with many other formats. In scripts that produce files and feed them directly to GS I've seen the .gs extension used to indicate a file made for GS, as opposed to a generic ps file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My major problem was to know the extension for ghostscript files, but now I'll which of you guys helped me the most. ;) 
Thanks!

Comment: @user142095 that's a much trickier question, actually. As mentioned in my other comment, GS can handle a lot of file formats.

Comment: @sparr my system has 0 files with .gs ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ghostscript files tend to have an extension `.ps`. You can find files ending in `.ps` with...

```
sudo find / -name *.ps -print
```

You will need sudo if you want to search the whole disc. If you want to put the result into a text file you can append `> results.txt` after that command.

If you know more about the file name you can change the * to search for that.

Examples:

```
$sudo find / -name *.ps -print
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_cidfm.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_cet.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_mro_e.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_cmap.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_std_e.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_agl.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_dps2.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_cidtt.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_dpnxt.ps
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Init/gs_diskn.ps
```